# Emulate Numpad: Negating a number value while hovering mouse cursor over value box?

Tags: shortcut

Usually without the emulate numpad feature on, pressing the minus key while hovering over a numeric value would multiply the value by -1. However, with the emulate numpad on, that negation doesn't seem to work anymore. Is there a way to set that negation shortcut to another key somehow?

Comment: I'm curious about this feature, on my end it zooms the field's panel out (and + zooms in)